# How do I get the middle element from random iterators beg and end?

Tags: c++, merge

```
RAIterator mid = beg + (end-beg)/2;
```

that makes mid = beg.

```
RAIterator mid = (beg+end)/2;
```

that gives an error

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

my entire code segment is

```
  template < class RAIterator , class Comparator >
  void g_merge_sort (RAIterator beg, RAIterator end, Comparator& cmp)
  {
    if (beg == end)
        return;

    RAIterator mid = (beg+end)/2;

    std::cout<<*mid<<std::endl;

    g_merge_sort(beg, mid, cmp);

    g_merge_sort(mid, end, cmp);

    mergesort::Merge (beg, mid, end, cmp);

  }
```

relevant definitions from the program calling merge_sort follow

```
typedef uint32_t ElementType;

ElementType * data = new ElementType [size];

g_merge_sort(data , data + dataStore.Size(), lts);
```

Comment: The first line of code is correct. The assertion in the statement below it is not, except in cases where `(end-beg) < 2`.

Comment: I certainly agree, but my system disagrees.  That's why I have that cout below it, it prints the first element then the recursive calls print the same first element until it eventually segfaults.

Comment: that was the problem thanks.  It was printing the first element because it was getting to it so fast that's all I saw.  It was because I wasn't checking for the size of end-beg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be most flexible you can use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

```
RAIterator mid = beg + std::distance(beg, end) / 2;
```

That shouldn't have delivered a different result than `beg + (end-beg)/2` though.

Note that if `mid == end`, the `*mid` is going to give you undefined behavior when `end` is past the end of the container.